# Using callbacks with optional parameters

Tags: javascript

I've seen libraries taking advantages of optional parameters and callbacks when writing functions. I'm writing a library, and I would like to know if it is a good practice to allow the user to skip the optional parameters and just send the callback.

For example:

```
function listFiles(params, callback) {
  if (typeof params === 'function' && !callback) {
    callback = params;
    params = {};
  }
  // more code here...
}
```

Users of my library can call `listFiles()` with parameters:

```
listFiles({ verbose: true }, function callback(err, results) { /*... */ })
```

or passing only the `callback()` function:

```
listFiles(function callback(err, results) { /*... */ })
```

The main benefit I see with this approach is that users won't have to do:

```
listFiles(null, function callback(err, results) { /*... */ })
```

or

```
listFiles({}, function callback(err, results) { /*... */ })
```

The problem is that if I make `verbose` a required parameter I will be breaking users that were not sending `params` along with the ones that were sending empty or null as `params`.

Should I use optional parameters as a callback or is this a bad idea?

Comment: Adding as a comment because this is more of a rule-of-thumb: If you reasonably expect that the first argument could become required, don't make it optional. Personally, the stability afforded by making `params` required (rather than allowing just the callback) is better than minor convenience of not having to specify `null` or `{}`.

Comment: Why not make parameters the second parameter? Then you could just detect if it's defined or not.

Comment: @ChrisHappy not speaking for OP, but callback-as-last-argument is a widely-used JS convention. IMO it would be worse to break with that

Comment: I think that JS developers are used to seeing the callback at the end, not the beginning but you have a good point there.

Comment: @FeifanZ Gotcha. Didn't know that. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not make `callback` one of the params so users always pass a single argument to `listFiles()`?

```
function listFiles(params) {
    // ... check for optional params and do something with them
    params.callback(err, result);
}
```

Now as a user I can pass the optional params if I want (using `limit` and `sort` as examples):

```
listFiles({
    limit: 10,
    sort: 'desc',
    callback: (err, result) => {
        // ... do something with result
    }
});
```

Or just the required `callback` param if I want to allow `listFiles()` to provide defaults for me:

```
listFiles({
    callback: (err, result) => {
        // ... do something with result
    }
});
```